# Withdraw from EtherDelta to Metamask

Tags: metamask

Why cant I transfer my Ethereum to my Metamask, each time I try it tells me I have insufficient balance for transaction.  I put in the exact balance to transfer?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to have some ETH in your wallet for gas fees.

IE if you're transferring .2 ETH from ED to a Metamask wallet from say, you'll need to have enough in your wallet to cover gas fees, which I think might be around.002 ETH.

If you don't have any in your wallet, you can send it to your MM wallet address.

Hope that helps.

Comment: No problem.  If it helped you, can you mark this is the answer?

Comment: I would if I knew how too.  james c